# ZeroClipboard not working on my website server

Tags: javascript, html, flash, zeroclipboard

I have uploaded all ZeroClipboard files (latest stable version, v1.2.3) to my server and cannot get a very simple demo of its use to work.

The [demo](http://webzeppelin.info/copy-text.htm) I am trying to use on my Unix server, and is not working, is virtually an exact copy of another [online demo](http://ready2gosoft.com/1/example1_c.html) that is working for me in all browsers.  The debug consoles are telling me there are no errors in the main ZeroClipboard.js file installed on my server. I have tried a variety of things suggested on this site for similar problems with ZeroClipboard with no success.

Can anyone shed any light on what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your JavaScript *before* the DOM is ready.  `document.getElementById('clip_copy')` doesn't exist at the time when you are calling it.

Try this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard( 
        document.getElementById('clip_copy'), {
        moviePath: "zeroclipboard-1.2.3/ZeroClipboard.swf"
    });
};
```

Comment: Just putting it after the button, as the working demo does, would be enough. No reason to wait for onload, which could be quite a bit later.

Comment: @hobbs: I like to put *all* my JavaScript in my `<head>`, so I prefer `onload` handlers.

Comment: You may like it, but the user who has to wait for the last image or whatever to load before the page becomes interactive doesn't.

Comment: @hobbs: Then use `DOMContentLoaded` or whatever.  I, personally, like to use events to run my JavaScript, so that way the problem isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Rocket Hazmat!  Perhaps you can help me now with the post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054302/using-zeroclipboard-to-copy-a-table-with-html-and-inline-styles.